# How can you remove the XML schema datattype from sparql query?

Tags: xsd, rdf, semantic-web, sparql, owl

Im running a sparql query on a file that contains

```
<User rdf:about="#RJ">
<hasName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">RJ</hasName>
</User>
```

I want to return only the name i.e. 'RJ' but when i enter my query

```
SELECT ?name
FROM <example.com> 
WHERE { 
       assign:RJ assign:hasName ?name .   
}
```

where assign is the correct namespace i return this :

```
"RJ" ^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
```

does anyone have any advice on how to remove the xml schema type for a sparql noob?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

Whether you can do this depends on the SPARQL implementation you are using.  Under SPARQL 1.0 this isn't possible, however with [SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) which is now widely supported by most implementations having become a W3C recommendation in March 2013 you can use [Project Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#selectExpressions) as follows:

```
SELECT (STR(?name) AS ?StringName)
FROM <example.com>
WHERE {
    assign:RJ assign:hasName ?name
}
```

Basically a project expression allows you to use any valid SPARQL expression which you could use elsewhere to calculate a new value based on the variables which are previously bound.